# Xcode 6.1 builds crashing on device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I recently made the mistake of upgrading to Xcode 6.1 (release version - 6A1052d) from 6.0.1 where everything was working fine. Upon first loading the project, I immediately had numerous errors, which I corrected by removing ?s or adding !s and commenting out an Apple supplied line from the persistent store coordinator in the app delegate:

```
// error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
```

My app now runs fine in the simulator, but on my device it crashes almost immediately after the build succeeds and takes me to lldb with almost no useful information. Currently it crashes on my first println statements, but I've tried bypassing things and it will still crash on simple variable declarations or println. I've tried updating my iOS, deleting the old app from my devices and restarting the devices. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: does this crash depend on your build configuration? I.e. does it happen when you build for debug, as well as for release?

Comment: What is the "almost no" error information, what kind of crash?

Comment: What is the error that is being returned when you attempt to add the store to the persistent store coordinator? That is where the problem is according to the information in your question. When you are opening the store and adding it, that is failing and the application is hitting `abort()`. Look at the error that is being returned.

Comment: Its crashing in both debug and release. Its giving me a: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdife). It doesn't make it as far as the persistent store coordinator. It seems to crash on whatever my first println or variable declaration is. It does execute a method call in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions but crashes on the first line of that method. I've tried bypassing things on launch but so far everything has crashed. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Well, I just ran Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1027) Beta, loaded my old app before the update and it runs fine on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what caused this problem in the first place, but I deleted Xcode, re-downloaded it, installed it, reloaded my old project, re-fixed my errors and the project is running now running on devices in the newest version of Xcode.